# Div inside a A attribute not working?

Tags: html

I have a peculiar question. I have made a div (code for which will be provided below), and I want the entire div (since it is a button) to be a clickable link. The issue I'm having is my div should only be 200x200, yet the think stretches across the entire page horizontally. It should only be a link in that 200x200 portion, but like I said it goes that 200 height across the entire horizontal part of the page making random background images clickable. I've tried setting the divs to block, with no avail. How would I solve this? My code is as follows.

```
#button {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

<a href="signup.php"><div id="button"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;`.  You could also do this without the `<div>` at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/SLAfU/

Answer (score 1):

You should do it following way:

```
#button {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

<a href="signup.php" id="button"></a>
```

Since anchors cannot contain block elements in HTML 4.01. Therefore you can just make anchor a block element and all will work.

In HTML5 anchors can contain block elements, therefore setting `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` combined with `<!DOCTYPE html>` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Make the anchor tag "display: inline-block"

You need to have an HTML5 doctype to have a div (block level element) inide an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

the right way in this case is:

```
<div id="button"><a href="signup.php"></a></div>
```

or

```
<div id="button" onclick="document.location.href='signup.php'" style="text-decoration:underline"></div>
```

read w3c specifications! you cant put block element inside inline!!!